# Prove a vector identity for $\boldsymbol{\nabla} \left( \hat{\mathbf{r}} \cdot \mathbf{r}^\prime \right)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

**Context**

I am studying radiation fields using [1]. In Eq. 20.98 in [1]  I  came across an identity (see Eq 1). I have attempted to use the the chain rule, and product rule and other identities found [2], [3], and [4] to demonstrate this identity and have not succeeded.

**Question**

Given two vector fields $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r}^\prime$, where $\mathbf{r} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{r}^\prime \in \mathbb{R}^n$,  the unit vector $\hat{\mathbf{r}}$, and that the differential operator $\boldsymbol{\nabla}$ operates on $\mathbf{r}$, can you demonstrate that
$$\boldsymbol{\nabla}    \left(  \hat{\mathbf{r}}  \cdot \mathbf{r}^\prime \right)
 = \hat{\mathbf{r}} \times\left( 
 \hat{\mathbf{r}} \times \frac{\mathbf{r}^\prime}{r} 
 \right)
?\tag{1}$$

**My Attempt**

I know from [2] that
$$
  \nabla( \hat{\mathbf{r}}   \cdot \mathbf{r}^\prime
)  =\ ( \hat{\mathbf{r}}   \cdot \nabla)\mathbf{r}^\prime \,+\,  (\mathbf{r}^\prime \cdot \nabla) \hat{\mathbf{r}} \,+\,   \hat{\mathbf{r}}   {\times} (\nabla {\times}\mathbf{r}^\prime) \,+\,  \mathbf{r}^\prime {\times} (\nabla {\times}  \hat{\mathbf{r}}  ) .
$$
The third term on the right is zero, because the del operator acts on $\mathbf{r}$ and does not act on $\mathbf{r}^\prime$. The fourth term is zero according to the definition of the curl in spherical coordinates.
Now, I know also from [2] that in spherical coordinates
\begin{align}
(\mathbf{A}  \cdot  \boldsymbol{\nabla})\mathbf{B} 
=
  \left(
    A_r \frac{\partial B_r}{\partial r}
  + \frac{A_\theta}{r} \frac{\partial B_r}{\partial \theta}
  + \frac{A_\varphi}{r\sin\theta} \frac{\partial B_r}{\partial \varphi}
  - \frac{A_\theta B_\theta + A_\varphi B_\varphi}{r}
  \right) &\hat{\mathbf r} \\
+ \left(
    A_r \frac{\partial B_\theta}{\partial r}
  + \frac{A_\theta}{r} \frac{\partial B_\theta}{\partial \theta}
  + \frac{A_\varphi}{r\sin\theta} \frac{\partial B_\theta}{\partial \varphi}
  + \frac{A_\theta B_r}{r} - \frac{A_\varphi B_\varphi\cot\theta}{r}
  \right) &\hat{\boldsymbol \theta} \\
+ \left(
    A_r \frac{\partial B_\varphi}{\partial r}
  + \frac{A_\theta}{r} \frac{\partial B_\varphi}{\partial \theta}
  + \frac{A_\varphi}{r\sin\theta} \frac{\partial B_\varphi}{\partial \varphi}
  + \frac{A_\varphi B_r}{r}
  + \frac{A_\varphi B_\theta \cot\theta}{r}
  \right) &\hat{\boldsymbol \varphi}.
\end{align}
Thus,
\begin{align}
(\hat{\mathbf{r}}  \cdot  \boldsymbol{\nabla})\mathbf{r}^\prime
= \mathbf{0}
\end{align}
I arrive at
$$
\boxed{
  \boldsymbol{\nabla}( \hat{\mathbf{r}}   \cdot \mathbf{r}^\prime
)  = (\mathbf{r}^\prime \cdot   \boldsymbol{\nabla}) \hat{\mathbf{r}}   .}
$$
This is not that which I was supposed to prove.

**Bibliography**

[1] Zangwill, Modern Electrodynamics, 2013, p. 733.
[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

[4] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me write $\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{r}'$ to better distinguish $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r}'$. Then by [BAC-CAB rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product),

$$ \hat{\mathbf{r}} \times \left( \frac{\hat{\mathbf{r}}}{r} \times \mathbf{a} \right)
= \frac{\hat{\mathbf{r}} (\hat{\mathbf{r}} \cdot \mathbf{a}) - \mathbf{a} (\hat{\mathbf{r}} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{r}})}{r}. \tag{1} $$

On the other hand, writing $\mathbf{r} = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$ and noting that $r = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}$,

\begin{align*}
\nabla (\hat{\mathbf{r}} \cdot \mathbf{a})
&= \sum_{i} \mathbf{e}_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left( \frac{\mathbf{r}}{r} \cdot \mathbf{a} \right) \\
&= \sum_{i} \mathbf{e}_i \left[ \left( \frac{\mathbf{e}_i}{r} - \frac{\mathbf{r}x_i}{r^3} \right) \cdot \mathbf{a} \right] \\
&= \frac{\sum_{i} \mathbf{e}_i (\mathbf{e}_i \cdot \mathbf{a})}{r} - \frac{\left( \sum_{i} \mathbf{e}_i x_i \right)(\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{a})}{r^3} \\
&= \frac{\mathbf{a}}{r} - \frac{\mathbf{r} (\mathbf{r}\cdot\mathbf{a})}{r^3} \tag{2}
\end{align*}

From this, it actually turns out that

$$ \nabla (\hat{\mathbf{r}} \cdot \mathbf{a}) = -\hat{\mathbf{r}} \times \left( \frac{\hat{\mathbf{r}}}{r} \times \mathbf{a} \right). $$

Mathematica 13 also verifies this:

[image: Verification by Mathematica]

Answer (score 1):

$
\renewcommand\vec\mathbf
\newcommand\uvec[1]{\hat{\vec#1}}
$First
$$
  \nabla(\uvec r\cdot\vec　r') = \nabla(\frac{\vec r}r\cdot\vec r') = (\nabla\frac1r)(\vec r\cdot\vec r') + \frac1r\nabla(\vec r\cdot\vec r').
$$
The second term we get from the fundamental identity
$$
  \nabla(\vec r\cdot\vec r') = \vec r'.
\tag{$*$}
$$
For the first term we use the chain rule to get
$$
  \nabla\frac1r = \frac{-\nabla r}{r^2} = \frac{-\uvec r}{r^2}.
$$
Thus all together
$$
  \nabla(\uvec r\cdot\vec　r') = \frac{-\uvec r}r(\uvec r\cdot\vec r') + \frac{\vec r'}r.
$$
Because $\uvec r\cdot\uvec r = 1$ we can rearrange and write
$$
  \nabla(\uvec r\cdot\vec　r') = \frac1r(\uvec r\cdot\uvec r)\vec r' - \frac1r(\uvec r\cdot\vec r')\uvec r
$$
so finally by the BAC-CAB identity
$$
  \nabla(\uvec r\cdot\vec　r') = \frac1r\uvec r\times(\vec r'\times\uvec r)
$$
which actually differs from the desired identity by a minus sign.

---

This is indeed the exact same thing as
$$
  (\vec r'\cdot\nabla)\uvec r
$$
because we have another fundamental identity closely related to ($*$):
$$
  (\vec r'\cdot\nabla)\vec r = \vec r'.
$$
If you expand $(\vec r'\cdot\nabla)\uvec r$ by writing $\uvec r = \vec r/r$ like I did above, then you will quickly see that we arrive at the same result.

Comment: Your answer would be improved if you expand the mathematics germane to the statement "from the fundamental identity..."

Comment: Your answers differs from by a minus sign. Does that imply that you have overlooked a minute detail?

Comment: @MichaelLevy Yes, your identity is incorrect. My final identity is the same as the one Sangchul Lee gives in the answer you accepted, but you did not question them about.

Comment: As for the "fundamental identities", note that $(\mathbf a\cdot\nabla)\mathbf r$ is precisely the directional derivative of the identity function in the $\mathbf a$ direction, so evidently $(\mathbf a\cdot\nabla)\mathbf r = \mathbf a$. Note that this true for *all* constant $\mathbf a$.

Comment: Now dot with an arbitrary constant vector $\mathbf b$ to get $$(\mathbf a\cdot\nabla)(\mathbf b\cdot \mathbf r) = \mathbf b\cdot \mathbf a.$$ The LHS can be rearranged to get $$[\nabla(\mathbf b\cdot\mathbf r)]\cdot\mathbf a = \mathbf b\cdot \mathbf a.$$ Because this is true for all $\mathbf a$ it must be that $$\nabla(\mathbf b\cdot\mathbf r) = \mathbf b$$ for all constant $\mathbf b$.

Answer (score 0):

I was really confused by the notations and might be completely lost without reading other answers. It actually ended up that the $\mathbf{r}^\prime$ is a constant vector if I am wrong otherwise.
$$
\nabla(\hat{\mathbf{r}}\cdot\mathbf{r}^\prime
)=\require{cancel}\cancel{(\hat{\mathbf{r}}\cdot \nabla)\mathbf{r}^\prime}+\require{cancel} \cancel{(\mathbf{r}^\prime \cdot \nabla) \hat{\mathbf{r}}}+\hat{\mathbf{r}}   {\times} (\nabla {\times}\mathbf{r}^\prime)+\require{cancel} \cancel{\mathbf{r}^\prime {\times} (\nabla {\times}  \hat{\mathbf{r}})}.
$$
As mentioned several times by Nicholas Todoroff. This involves indeed some "fundamental identities" which we are not aware of. For instance for an $m-$dimensional functional $f(\mathbf{r})$ and $\mathbf{r}=[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$, the following is a list I have derived one by one by hand and hope experts can help to check and make it useful.
\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot(r^n\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{r}}})&=\nabla\cdot(r^{n-1}\mathbf{r})=r^{n-1}\nabla\cdot\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{r}\cdot\nabla r^{n-1}=(m+n-1)r^{n-1}\\
\nabla\cdot\frac{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{r}}}}{r^n}&=\nabla\cdot\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{r^{n+1}}\nabla\cdot\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{r}\cdot\nabla\frac{1}{r^{n+1}}=\frac{m-1-n}{r^{n+1}}\label{eq:Diverger^-n}\\
\nabla{r^n}&=n{r^{n-1}}\nabla r=n{r^{n-1}}\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{r}}}=n{r^{n-2}}\mathbf{r}\\
\nabla\frac{1}{r^n}&=\frac{-n\nabla r}{r^{n+1}}=\frac{-n\mathbf{r}}{r^{n+2}}\\
\nabla^2\frac{1}{r^n}&=\nabla\cdot\nabla\frac{1}{r^n}=\frac{n(n+2-m)}{r^{n+2}}\\
\nabla\times\mathbf{r}&=0\\
\nabla\times\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{r}}}&=\frac{1}{r}\nabla\times\mathbf{r}+\nabla\frac{1}{r}\times\mathbf{r}=0-\frac{\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{r}}{r^3}=0
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\nabla(\mathbf{A} \cdot\mathbf{B})&=\underbrace{(\mathbf{A} \cdot\nabla)\mathbf{B}+\mathbf{A} {\times}(\nabla{\times}\mathbf{B})}_{=\mathbf{A} \cdot\nabla\!\!\mathbf{B}}+\underbrace{(\mathbf{B}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{A} +\mathbf{B}{\times}(\nabla{\times}\mathbf{A} )}_{=\mathbf{B}\cdot\nabla\!\!\mathbf{A} }\\
&=\mathbf{A} \cdot\mathbf{J}^{\!\!\top}_{\!\!\mathbf{B}}+\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{J}^{\!\!\top}_{\!\!\mathbf{A} }=\mathbf{A} \cdot\nabla\!\!\mathbf{B}+\mathbf{B}\cdot\nabla\!\!\mathbf{A} 
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{J}^{\!\!\top}_{\!\!\mathbf{A} }=\nabla\!\!\mathbf{A} = (\partial A_j/\partial x_i)_{ij}=(\partial_iA_j)$ denotes the transposed Jacobian matrix of the vector field $\mathbf{A} =(A_1,\ldots,A_n)$, and in the last expression the $\cdot$ operations are understood not to act on the $\nabla$ directions (different definition in [Wiki:Vector_calculus_identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities), but to inner-product of the vector immediately after $\nabla$. Alternatively, using Feynman subscript notation,
\begin{align}
\nabla(\mathbf{A} \cdot\mathbf{B}) = \nabla_{\mathbf{A} }(\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B}) + \nabla_{\mathbf{B}}(\mathbf{A} \cdot\mathbf{B}).
\end{align}

Note the difference:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A} \cdot\nabla\mathbf{B}&=\nabla_{\!\mathbf{B}}(\mathbf{A} \cdot\mathbf{B})=\mathbf{A} \cdot\mathbf{J}^{\!\!\top}_{\!\!\mathbf{B}}=A_j\left({\frac{\partial B_j}{\partial x_i}}\right)=\sum_jA_j\partial_iB_j\\
(\mathbf{A} \cdot\nabla)\mathbf{B}&=\left(A_j{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}}\right)B_i=\mathbf{A} \cdot\mathbf{J}_{\!\!\mathbf{B}}=A_j\left({\frac{\partial B_i}{\partial x_j}}\right)=\sum_jA_j\partial_jB_i
\end{align}
**Note**: the squeezed notation is to emphasize the connection and please remove it if annoying.