What is the Laplacian of the Gradient? Is $\boldsymbol{u}(\nabla\cdot\nabla p) = \nabla (\boldsymbol{u}\cdot\nabla p)$?
I am supposed to find out whether for a

scalar function $p$ and a
divergence-free vector function $\boldsymbol{u}$

we have that
$$\nabla\cdot\Big [\boldsymbol{u}(\nabla\cdot\nabla p) - \nabla (\boldsymbol{u}\cdot\nabla p)\Big]=0.$$
Approach 1: Gradient of dot product
I use https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Gradient_of_Dot_Product and try to show that the second term in the brackets is equal to the first:
$$\nabla (\boldsymbol{u}\cdot\nabla p) = (\boldsymbol{u}\cdot\nabla)\nabla p+(\nabla p\cdot\nabla)\boldsymbol{u} + \boldsymbol{u}\times (\nabla\times \nabla p) + \nabla p \times (\nabla\times \boldsymbol{u})$$
This, however, is an endless game, I dont see a clear end to where this goes.
Approach 2: BAC-CAB
I try to use https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BAC-CABIdentity.html to rewrite the expression inside the brackets:
$$\boldsymbol{u}(\nabla\cdot\nabla p) - \nabla (\boldsymbol{u}\cdot\nabla p) = \nabla p\times (\nabla\times\boldsymbol{u}) $$
This is not necessarily $0$. However I am not sure that I am allowed to use the identity that way.
Approach 3: Gradient of Laplacian
In this question Does the Laplacian and gradient commute? I learned that $\nabla (\Delta p) = \Delta (\nabla p)$. I tried to use this on the first term. Further we know that the divergence-free property always allows to write $\nabla\cdot (\boldsymbol{u}p) = \boldsymbol{u}\cdot\nabla p$.
$$
\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot\Big [\boldsymbol{u}(\nabla\cdot\nabla p) \Big ] 
&= \boldsymbol{u}\cdot\nabla(\nabla\cdot\nabla p)\\
&= \boldsymbol{u}\cdot\nabla(\Delta p)\\
&= \boldsymbol{u}\cdot \Delta (\nabla p)
\end{align}
$$
Can I know pull in the $\boldsymbol{u}$, like this:
$$\boldsymbol{u}\cdot \Delta (\nabla p) \stackrel{?}{=} \Delta (\boldsymbol{u}\cdot \nabla p)$$
That would be great, as the second term of my problem is exactly this. However, I think I am cheating here. What does it mean to take the Laplacian of a Gradient?
When I try to show if the divergence free property allows this last move, i get
$$\boldsymbol{u}\cdot \Delta (\nabla p)  = \boldsymbol{u}\cdot[\nabla\cdot\nabla (\nabla p)]$$
but I can not make sense of the divergence of the gradient of a gradient. Any help is much appreciated.

Can you please write clearer your question title $\nabla\cdot (u\nabla(\nabla p))$?

Yes sorry, i tried to make it more fitting. Feel free to suggest a more suitable one, if you have one in mind.

I don't think they are equal. Left $\mathbf{u}(\nabla\cdot\nabla p)=u_i\partial_j\partial_jp=\mathbf{u}\nabla^2p$, whereas the right $\nabla (\boldsymbol{u}\cdot\nabla p)=\partial_i(u_j\partial_jp)=u_j\partial_{ij}p+\partial_jp\partial_i\partial_{ij}u=\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla(\nabla p)+\nabla p\cdot\nabla\mathbf{u}$.

I do think you tried a lot. Maybe it is useful to see one post or my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4771359.

are you sure that your second identity, i.e. $\partial_i(u_h\partial_jp) = ...$ is true? When I apply this, I get something completely different involving cross products. However, I am not very familiar with index notation and cant spot your mistake directly.

As notation suggests, the second $\mathbb u$ has no argument, so how to get $\nabla$ into?

I dont understand what you mean with $\mathbb{u}$ has no argument. In my post $\boldsymbol{u}$ is a vector function, and in general dependent on $x,y,z$.
